# import a project on another project with gradle on eclipse

Tags: spring, import, gradle

I'm trying to use Gradle as Spring MVC project builder. I divide my project in two distinct ones, the first project will contain the Repository and service part, and the second one, the views and controllers (web part)

My problem is when I try to deploy my project, the server don't see the entities from the first project. It also doesn't deploy this first project.

I think it due to Gradle, but I don't know how to indicate to gradle to import the first project on the second one.

Comment: Can you post your build.gradle?

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a multi project with the following hirarchy:

- Root Project

  - settings.gradle
  - service

    - build.gradle
    - ...
  - web

    - build.gradle
    - ...

The settings.gradle has to include the following

```
include 'service'
include 'web'
```

Now the web project can use the service project with the following code in the build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':service')
}
```